# Why am I getting an error when trying to test if a program is running?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to test if Excel is running.  When I have Excel open, it still returns "not found" as well as the following error: "The search filter cannot be recognized"

```
tasklist /nh /fi "image name eq EXCEL.exe" | find /i "EXCEL.exe" > nul &&(
echo found
)|| (
echo not found
)

pause
```

Comment: Typo: `imagename` shouldn't have the space between words. Run `tasklist /?` to see the options.

Comment: Thanks I'm sorry I didn't notice that.  I understand that the && is if the statement is true and the || is for false, but what is the "> nul" for?

Comment: `>nul` hides the console output of the command

Comment: I see and thanks for your help.  Last question, I promise - why is no "If" statement required in the beginning?  I know I have seen those in batch files before

Comment: Also, `/NH` is only valid when you use the `/FO TABLE` or `/FO CSV` switches. You can/should omit it otherwise.

Comment: Is the output of /fi considered a table?

Comment: No `IF` statement in the beginning is required because you are using the `/FI`lter method of `Tasklist`. The "if" is built in.